# Android: Read file data from BLOB in WebView using JavaScript Interface

Tags: javascript, android

**Objective**

Download `CSV/XLSX` files generated in the browser in Android `WebView`
Files are being generated using `alasql` in the web app itself.

**Current Status**

Added a `JavaScriptInterface` to the `WebView`.

Added a `function` to fire an `xhr GET` request on the obtained `blobUrl`, over here I only get the first 250-400 characters of the BLOB.

JavaScriptInterface: [gist](https://gist.github.com/utkarshns/6a774474a36f20c343fc49b28de69960)

WebView snippet:
mWebView = (AdvancedWebView) findViewById(R.id.iosense);
        mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "Android");

```
    mWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDownloadStart(String blobUrl, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimeType, long contentLength) {
            mWebView.loadUrl(JavaScriptInterface.getBlobData(blobUrl));
        }
    });
```

**Help needed with**

Getting the entire BLOB data and saving it as a file on the Android device.

Comment: You could hire someone to make this

Comment: or edit your post and better explain what you've tried, what went wrong, show your code, show what internet resources you used

Comment: Sure, updating the post with code.